# Help differentiating $\frac{(x-1)^2(x+2)^2}{(x+1)^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need help differentiating this expression below. I know you can use a mix of the product rule and quotient rule, but that is tedious and long. Is there a shorter method?

$$\dfrac{(x-1)^2(x+2)^2}{(x+1)^2}$$

Comment: You can write the denominator as a negative power and then you have only the product rule to remember. Other than that, there is no shorter method. And it only looks tedious and long the first few times you do it. Remember how difficult and long 3-digit multiplications seemed in primary school? This too will get easier with practice.

Comment: @Nick there's always [a way out](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2230990/413023)

Comment: @DHMO: Shorter? Simpler? All in the eye of the beholder...

Comment: @Nick right, your method is also quite nice; would you like to post it?

Comment: Not really - if the OP posted a homework problem, then solving it for him/her on SE does nobody any favors. In any case, I think the hint should be enough to allow the OP to do the calculation; if not, then it is much more helpful to talk to the teacher/professor/TA about it, than be given the answer.

Comment: @Nick I consider "searching for short and elegant solutions" to be in the spirit of mathematics instead of requesting to be spoonfed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57008/discussion-between-nick-and-dhmo).

Answer (score 7):

**Another approach:**

Let $$y=\frac{(x-1)^2(x+2)^2}{(x+1)^2}$$
Then,
\begin{align*}
\ln y&=2\ln (x-1)+2\ln(x+2)-2\ln(x+1)\\
\qquad \frac{y'}{y}&=\frac2{x-1}+\frac2{x+2}-\frac2{x+1}\\
\qquad y'&=\left(\frac2{x-1}+\frac2{x+2}-\frac2{x+1}\right)\frac{(x-1)^2(x+2)^2}{(x+1)^2}\\
\end{align*}

Although we have suppose that $x-1,\;x+2$ and $x+1$ are positive the obtained derivative holds whenever $x\neq \pm1,-2.$

---

Generally speaking, whenever you want to differentiate some sort of fraction with degrees $>1$, it is usually best to take the $\ln$ of both sides, and then this will clean up your original function a lot.

Comment: ... and leave you with having to prove that the result is valid even where the log arguments are negative (which might or might not be important). But if one is cavalier about such things, errors creep in without one realizing it. How do you prove that your result is valid for all values of x?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \frac{(x-1)^2(x+2)^2}{(x+1)^2}&=\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \left(\frac{(x-1)(x+2)}{x+1}\right)^2\\
&=\displaystyle \frac{2(x-1)(x+2)}{x+1} \left( \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \frac{(x-1)(x+2)}{x+1} \right)\\
&=\displaystyle \frac{2(x-1)(x+2)}{x+1} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \left( \frac{x^2+x-2}{x+1} \right)\\
&=\displaystyle \frac{2(x-1)(x+2)}{x+1} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \left( \frac{(x+1)x-2}{x+1} \right)\\
&=\displaystyle \frac{2(x-1)(x+2)}{x+1} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \left(x - \frac{2}{x+1} \right)\\
&=\displaystyle \frac{2(x-1)(x+2)}{x+1} \left(1 + \frac{2}{(x+1)^2} \right)\\
&=\displaystyle \frac{2(x-1)(x+2)}{x+1} \cdot \frac{x^2+2x+3}{(x+1)^2}\\
&=\displaystyle \frac{2(x-1)(x+2)(x^2+2x+3)}{(x+1)^3}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Use this way for a short-cut :

Let :

$$f(x) = \dfrac{(x-1)^2(x+2)^2}{(x+1)^2}$$

$$\ln {f(x)} = \ln (x-1)^2 +\ln(x+2)^2-\ln(x+1)^2 $$

$$\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{2(x-1)}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{2(x+2)}{(x+2)^2}-\frac{2(x+1)}{(x+1)^2} $$

$$f'(x) =  \dfrac{(x-1)^2(x+2)^2}{(x+1)^2} \Bigg(\frac{2}{(x-1)}+\frac{2}{(x+2)}-\frac{2}{(x+1)} \Bigg)$$

Comment: Not only is this the same approach as another answer, but it's unnecessarily complicated. (To differentiate $\ln(x-1)^2$, first rewrite it as $2\ln(x-1)$. Note that your derivative is $\frac{2(x-1)}{(x-1)^2}$, which is just $\frac2{x-1)}$.)

Comment: Why downvote  @Théophile ?Because  mine and Ángel's answer are the same? It takes time to type, therefore it may easily take more than 2mins to type that stuff.

Comment: Also, what did you just say...It takes *effort* to rewrite $\ln(x-1)^2$ as $2\ln(x-1)$?  Really? What about @DHMO's answer then?

Comment: Upvoted because this is a perfectly valid method, and I saw no evidence of copying

Comment: Thanks @mrnovice :) Atleast someone is on my side.

Comment: For me it is also a valid answer. The time's lack is just 3 min. (+1)

Comment: This happens always with me :D You know @Arnaldo ! (Remember me?)

Comment: You are missing a factor of 2.

Comment: @Nick Thanks.Fixed.

Comment: @JaideepKhare I'm not accusing you of copying another answer; I'm just pointing out that your answer is effectively redundant. I agree that it's a valid method, but the method is the same as Angel's, who has done it more efficiently and with more information. No need to take it personally.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x):=\left(\dfrac{g(x)}{h(x)}\right)^n\implies{}f'(x)=n\ \dfrac{g(x)^{n-1}}{h(x)^{n+1}}\left(g'(x)\,h(x)-g(x)\,h'(x)\right)$$

In your case, $n=2$ as well as

$g(x)=(x-1)\cdot(x+2)\ \ \ $ and $\ \ \ h(x)=x+1$,

leading to derivatives $g'$ and $h'$ that are linear in $x$.

You'll be okay.

Answer (score 1):

In fact we do not need a mix of quotient and product rule. Applying the product rule once is sufficient.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{d}{dx}&\frac{(x-1)^2(x+2)^2}{(x+1)^2}\\
> &=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\color{blue}{(x^2+x-2)^2}\color{red}{(x+1)^{-2}}\right]\\
> &=\color{blue}{2(x^2+x-2)(2x+1)}\color{red}{(x+1)^{-2}}+\color{blue}{(x^2+x-2)^2}\color{red}{(-2)(x+1)^{-3}}\\
> &=\frac{2(x^2+x-2)}{(x+1)^3}\left[(2x+1)(x+1)-(x^2+x-2)\right]\\
> &=\frac{2(x^2+x-2)(x^2+2x+3)}{(x+1)^3}
> \end{align*}